# When sending many of the same HttpWebRequests with BeginGetResponse, a small percentage do not complete

Tags: c#, .net

I am testing the throughput of HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse.  Each time a request completes or an exception occurs, I am incrementing a counter and outputting it to the console window.  When sending 10,000 of the same HttpWebRequest, I am seeing different final outputs of 9969, 9977, it varies really, but never outputs the expected final count of 10000.

```
public partial class TestingForm : Form
{

    public TestingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var completed = 0;
        var callback = new Action<String, Exception>((r, ex) =>
        {
            completed++;
            Console.WriteLine(completed);
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
            req.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.2:8888");
            WebHelper.BeginGetResponse(req, callback);
        }
    }
}
```

**WebHelper.BeginGetResponse**

```
public static void BeginGetResponse(WebRequest request, Action<WebResponse, Exception> callback)
{
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((result) =>
    {
        WebResponse resp = null;
        Exception exception = null;
        try
        {
            resp = request.EndGetResponse(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }
        callback.BeginInvoke(resp, exception, null, null);
    }), null);
}

public static void BeginGetResponse(WebRequest request, Action<String, Exception> callback)
{
    BeginGetResponse(request, new Action<WebResponse, Exception>(async (resp, ex) =>
    {
        string response = null;
        if (ex == null)
        {
            using (resp)
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    response = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        callback.BeginInvoke(response, ex, null, null);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Please don't include tags in titles. Tags are for tags. They are just clutter in titles.

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing my counter using Interlocked.Increment solved the problem.

```
public partial class TestingForm : Form
{

    public TestingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var completed = 0;
        var callback = new Action<String, Exception>((r, ex) =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref completed);
            Console.WriteLine(completed);
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
            req.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.2:8888");
            WebHelper.BeginGetResponse(req, callback);
        }
    }
}
```